# Relative precedence of let and if expressions

Tags: parsing, expressions, precedence

In a language with standard let and if expressions, what should be the their precedence such that they can be nested without parentheses?

For example, I want to be able to parse both of these expressions:

```
if let a = b in c then d else e
```

```
let a = if b then c else d in e
```

---

I am using [lalrpop](https://github.com/lalrpop/lalrpop) to generate a parser. My attempt looks like this:

```
grammar;

pub Expr: () = {
    #[precedence(level="0")]
    Name => { println!("Name: {}", <>); },

    #[precedence(level="1")]
    #[assoc(side="right")]
    "let" <name:Name> "=" <value:Expr> "in" <body:Expr> => { println!("Let: {}", name); },

    #[precedence(level="2")]
    "if" <check:Expr> "then" <then:Expr> "else" <els:Expr> => { println!("If"); },
};

Name: &'input str = r"[a-zA-Z_]+'?";
```

However, this can only parse the first of the above expressions. If I swap the precedence of the last two rules, then it can only parse the second!

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't believe this is a case of precedence conflict. The first keyword (`if` or `let`) allows to unambiguosly identify the applicable rule. The same goes for the nested expressions, so having a `let` in the `if`'s condition is perfectly fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this actually doesn't seem to be a precedence issue. I can get the desired behavior by removing the precedence annotations altogether:

```
grammar;

pub Expr: () = {
    Name => { println!("Name: {}", <>); },
    "let" <name:Name> "=" <value:Expr> "in" <body:Expr> => { println!("Let: {}", name); },
    "if" <check:Expr> "then" <then:Expr> "else" <els:Expr> => { println!("If"); },
};

Name: &'input str = r"[a-zA-Z_]+'?";
```

So the answer to the question is they should be at the *same* level.

Answer (score 3):

## Make `if let` a single construct

This is what Swift does (though it uses `,` rather than `in`):

```swift
if condition { /* okay */ }
if (condition) { /* okay */ }
if let a = b { /* okay */ }
if let a = b, condition { /* okay */ }
if (let a = b) { /* error */ }
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding to [@Bbrk24's answer](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/a/1454/89), Rust has [`if let`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-03-if-let.html) as a separate language construct with its own semantics, as opposed to just combining the semantics of an `if` expression with a `let` expression. Particularly, it allows the `let` binding to be a [refutable pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-02-refutability.html), unlike `let` in other contexts. (The same applies for `let` bindings in other conditional contexts, e.g. `while let`.)

For example, if `some_opt` is an [option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type):

```rust
if let Some(x) = some_opt {
    // ...
}
```

The statement `let Some(x) = some_opt;` by itself would be invalid since the pattern `Some(x)` is refutable; it doesn't match the value `None`. But this is allowed in an `if let` statement, where the variable `x` is bound only inside the conditional branch, and the conditional branch is executed only when the pattern does match (so that `x` does have a value).

If your language has [pattern matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching) and/or destructuring assignments already, then it may be worth including this construct in your language. In that case, there is no need to resolve any precedence issue between `if` and `let` when parsing `if let ...`, since this becomes just a single expression.

Comment: Swift `if let x = y` is specifically shorthand for `if case Optional.some(let x) = y`, so it is more semantically similar to Rust than to the let-in statement the OP has. However, Swift's shorthand is more _syntactically_ similar to the OP, and the question is about parsing, not semantics.